# How to calculate the previous month and year from string in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

With the input `value` holding today's date **2020 07 08 03:00** as a string:

```
value="202007080300"
```

I would like to go ahead and declare two other string variables. The first variable `start` would be the first day of the previous month. The second variable `end` would be the first day of the same month the `value` variable stores, for example it would be here:

```
start="202006010300"
end="202007010300"
```

It looks simple until you think what would happen if the `value` variable stores the first or the last of the month, such as:

```
value="202001020300"
```

or

```
value="198612090000"
```

The solution should work with any input values. How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the date/time string in correct format, in pure bash:

```
datetime="202007080300"

startyear=${datetime:0:4}
startmonth=${datetime:4:2}
startmonth=${startmonth#0}
startmonth=$((startmonth - 1))
if ((startmonth == 0)); then
    startmonth=12
    startyear=$((startyear - 1))
fi

printf -v start "%d%02d%02d%s" "$startyear" "$startmonth" 1 "${datetime:8}"
end="${datetime:0:6}01${datetime:8}"

echo "date  = $datetime"
echo "start = $start"
echo "end   = $end"
```